# Print an OpenGL Texture to File without Display?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to use OpenGL to help with processing Kinect depth map input into an image. At the moment we're using the Kinect as a basic motion sensor, and the program counts how many people walk by and takes a screen shot each time it detects someone new.

The problem is that I need to get this program to run without access to a display. We're wanting to run it remotely over SSH, and the network traffic from other services is going to be too much for X11 forwarding to be a good idea. Attaching a display to the machine running the program is a possibility, but we're wanting to avoid doing that for energy consumption reasons.

The program does generate a 2D texture object for OpenGL, and usually just uses GLUT to render it before a read the pixels and output them to a .PNG file using FreeImage. The issue I'm running into is that once GLUT function calls are removed, all that gets printed to the .PNG files are just black boxes.

I'm using the OpenNI and NITE drivers for the Kinect. The programming language is C++, and I'm needing to use Ubuntu 10.04 due to the hardware limitations of the target device.

I've tried using OSMesa or FrameBuffer objects, but I am a complete OpenGL newbie so I haven't gotten OSMesa to render properly in place of the GLUT functions, and my compilers can't find any of the OpenGL FrameBuffer functions in GL/glext.h or GL/gl.h.

I know that textures can be read into a program from image files, and all I want to output is a single 2-D texture. Is there a way to skip the headache of off-screen rendering in this case and print a texture directly to an image file without needing OpenGL to render it first?

Comment: Did you finally manage to do this off-screen rendering?

Answer (score 3):

The OSMesa library is neither a drop-in replacement for GLUT, nor can work together. If you only need the offscreen rendering part without interaction you have to implement a simple event loop yourself.

For example:

```
/* init OSMesa */
OSMesaContext        mContext;
void                *mBuffer;
size_t               mWidth;
size_t               mHeight;

// Create RGBA context and specify Z, stencil, accum sizes
mContext = OSMesaCreateContextExt( OSMESA_RGBA, 16, 0, 0, NULL );
OSMesaMakeCurrent(mContext, mBuffer, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mWidth, mHeight);
```

After this snipped you can use the normal OpenGL calls to render and after a **glFinish()** call the results can be accessed through the *mBuffer* pointer.

In you event loop you can call your normal *onDisplay*, *onIdle*, etc callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

> We're wanting to run it remotely over SSH, and the network traffic from other services is going to be too much for X11 forwarding to be a good idea.

If you forward X11 and create the OpenGL context on that display, OpenGL traffic will go over the net no matter if there is a window visible or not. So what you actually need to do (if you want to make use of GPU accelerated OpenGL) is starting an X server on the remote machine, and keeping it the active VT (i.e. the X server must be the program that "owns" the display). Then your program can make a connection to this very X server only. But this requires to use Xlib. Some time ago *fungus* wrote a minimalistic Xlib example, I extended it a bit so that it makes use of FBConfigs, you can find it here: https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl/x11argb_opengl.c

In your case you should render to a FBO or a PBuffer. *Never use a visible window framebuffer to render stuff that's to be stored away!* If you create a OpenGL window, like with the code I linked use a FBO. Creating a GLX PBuffer is not unlike creating a GLX Window, only that it will be off-screen.

The trick is, not to use the default X Display (of your SSH forward) but a separate connection to the local X Server. The key is the line

```
Xdisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
```

Instead of NULL, you'd pass the connection to the local server there. To make this work you'll also need to (manually) add an xauth entry to, or disable xauth on the OpenGL rendering server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glGetTexImage to read a texture back from OpenGL.

Comment: I think his problem is, that he wants to avoid round trips.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It didn't work for me, though I have solved my problem. Here's what I did: I took the 2d texture array and set up a FreeImage bitmap to match its dimensions. Then I had to rotate it 180 degrees. Then it was sent to a file.